# Is this an usage of Groovy collect closure abbreviation?

Tags: java, list, groovy, collect

I study the Groovy code which deals with JSON parsing and find the following strange code that I cannot understand:

list.groovy

```
def lst = [
    [name: 'Bill', age: 30],
    [name: 'Jobs', age: 40],
    [name: 'Steve', age: 50],
]

println lst
println lst.name
println lst.collect{it.name}
println lst.age
println lst.agenda
```

Platform: Windows 10, Groovy version: 2.5.9

```
C:\chenchang\study\groovy_study\closure>groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.5.9 JVM: 1.8.0_272 Vendor: AdoptOpenJDK OS: Windows 10
```

The output of the Groovy script:

```
C:\chenchang\study\groovy_study\closure>groovy list.groovy
[[name:Bill, age:30], [name:Jobs, age:40], [name:Steve, age:50]]
[Bill, Jobs, Steve]
[Bill, Jobs, Steve]
[30, 40, 50]
[null, null, null]
```

I cannot understand `lst.name` part. It looks like `lst.collect{it.name}` but I cannot find any reference documentation or formal explanations. Can anyone explain what Groovy syntax it is?

---

After reviewed your comments, I update the sample code and find some new knowledge that I don't know before.

```
def lst = [
    [name: 'Bill', age: 30],
    [name: 'Jobs', age: 40],
    [name: 'Steve', age: 50],
    null, // I add a null value in the list
]
println lst
println lst.name
println lst.findAll{ it != null }.collect{ it.name }
println lst*.name
/* println lst.collect{ it.name } */
/* java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object */
println lst.collect{ it?.name }
```

The output of the revised Groovy script:

```
C:\chenchang\study\groovy_study\closure>groovy list.groovy
[[name:Bill, age:30], [name:Jobs, age:40], [name:Steve, age:50], null]
[Bill, Jobs, Steve]
[Bill, Jobs, Steve]
[Bill, Jobs, Steve, null]
[Bill, Jobs, Steve, null]
```

`lst.name` is [GPath](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_gpath_support) which ignores the null values. So the length of the returned new list will be less than the length of the original list if the original list contains null values. `lst.name` is equivalent to `lst.findAll{ it != null }.collect{ it.name }`.

`lst*.name` is `spread dot operator` or [Star dot operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#Collections-Gettingefficientwiththestar-dotoperator). The length of the returned new list is equal to the length of the original list. If some values in the original list are `null`, the corresponding values in the new list will be null and no `NullPointerException` will be thrown. `lst*.name` is equivalent to `lst.collect{ it?.name }`.

Comment: Note that while it's technically _correct_, it's _unclear_, and in code review I'd replace it with `*.`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s the [GPath](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_gpath_support) notation for collections.

GPath can be used to process data such as XML, JSON and collections.

Comment: It's not.  It is the implicit spread operator.

Comment: Interesting, the docs I linked to suggest GPath, perhaps they’re wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`def lst = []` is a [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

you can use `println lst.getClass()` to check it

`ArrayList` implements `Iterable`, `Collection`, ... and other interfaces

groovy could add functionality on any level of super interface or super class.

[groovy gdk documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/) explains additional functionality that groovy adds to java

to get list of all available methods in groovy you have to check java doc and all super classes/interfaces of groovy doc.

in case of `lst.name` groovy actually calls `lst.getAt('name')`

getAt(String key) - you can find in groovy doc [Collection](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#getAt(java.lang.String))

and finally here is a doc about groovy collections: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html